# Display PL/SQL function warnings

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function pode_levar( pedidos NUMBER, viagens  NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
x NUMBER:=0;
y NUMBER:=0;
TRUE NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN

BEGIN
    Select id_pedido into x
    from pedido
    where id_pedido = pedidos;
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA FOUND THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICAITON_ERROR(-20305,'PEDIDO TRANSPORTE ENIXISTENTE');
END;

BEGIN
    select lim_vei_vol - volume_total_viagem(viagens)  into y
    from v viagem , ve veiculo
    where v.id_viagem = ve.id_viagem
    and id_viagem = viagens;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    TRUE:=0;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20304,'Viagem Enixistente');
    RETURN(TRUE);
END;

BEGIN 
    IF y <> 0 
    TRUE := 1;
    RETURN(TRUE);
    ELSE
    TRUE := 0;
    RETURN(TRUE);
    ENDIF;

END;

END;
```

The function compiles with one warning, how can I see it? `show errors` does not work

This is for school,

Comment: Which tool are you using to run that `create` statement` `show errors` **will** show any problems if you are usin SQL*Plus

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No warnings are displayed by `SHOW ERRORS` if not enabled in the session.

Comment: Does it say it compiled with warnings, or with errors?

Answer (score 5):

You should use SQL* Plus and set

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'ENABLE:ALL';
```

before you create your function. This setting will show you any warnings by using

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams186.htm#REFRN10249

Comment: You can do this from SQL Developer too; but if this is off then you will (or should, anyway) still see errors, and you wouldn't get the 'compiled with warnings' message if it's off? (I think... can't check right now...)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you aren't seeing this with `show errors` - possibly a buggy old version. You can try this instead:

```
select * from user_errors;
```

But you have your aliases declared the wrong way around and not always used when referencing the shared column:

```
from v viagem , ve veiculo
where v.id_viagem = ve.id_viagem
and id_viagem = viagens;
```

should be:

```
from viagem v, veiculo ve
where v.id_viagem = ve.id_viagem
```

and v.id_viagem = viagens;

Or even:

```
from viagem v
join veiculo ve
on v.id_viagem = ve.id_viagem
where v.id_viagem = viagens;
```

There <strike>may be</strike> are other problems too as Ben pointed out in comments, and you haven't shown any table definitions, but that wasn't really the question.

If you had warnings turned on too (which is in the preferences in SQL Developer) I'd guess it would point out that the `return` after the `raise` in the second block is unreachable. You can't do both.

Comment: The error in this case is `endif` and lack of `then` (and possibly the variable `TRUE`);

Comment: @Ben - right, missed that. It'll complain about the aliases at some point though, with invalid identifier?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I completely missed that :-). I don't know what Oracle tries to compile first actually. It'd be interesting to work it out one day.

Comment: Hey guys, the question was _how can I see it?_ (the warnings) and not _where is the syntax error_ ;-)

Comment: @Toru - agreed, that's why I started with `user errors`, and said 'that wasn't really the question'. Easy to get carried away though *8-)