# Im getting an Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: plsql

I'm beginner of pl/sql and I'm learning.

This is my table.

```
select * from s;

   SLNO ENAME                       SAL
------ -------------------- ----------
     1 Shiv                       8000
     2 Pankaj                     9000
     3 Prasath                   10000
```

This is my procedure:

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure p1(n number)
is wname varchar(20);
begin
select ename into wname from s where eid=n;
dbms_output.put_line('------');
dbms_output.put_line('employee name:='||wname);
dbms_output.put_line('------');
end;
```

I'm getting a warning:

> Procedure created with compilation errors.

If I execute the above query. Can anyone please suggest where I'm going wrong please..

Comment: Does it say what the compilation errors are?  What happens if you try to execute the procedure after creating it?

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing the details of the compilation error. One (probably unrelated) issue: you should be using `varchar2` instead of `varchar`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2 ...or if you want to do something really "cool", replace `wname varchar(20);` with `wname s.ename%type;` to ensure that `wname` will always be whatever type your column is.

Comment: Show warnings and errors as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013487/display-pl-sql-function-warnings/17013844#17013844

Comment: This is a boring syntax error question and the OP has shown no inclination to requests for further information.  So, voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command.

```
show errors procedure procedure_name;
```

to get the list of errors and check that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column named EID on your table S.

Answer (score 0):

put parameter type IN.
Give procedure like *create or replace procedure p1(n IN s.eid%TYPE)*

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo in your program,
try

```
SET SETVEROUTPUT ON
```

all in capitals.

Comment: it worked for me. even i did not care about case, but when case was capital, it worked for me. same applies to creating triggers.(tried, tested and successful) Cheers